# Limit $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 5}x^2=25$

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

From my book:

> **6.** With regard to the limit $\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow 5}x^2=25$,
>
> (a) Show that $\left |x^2-25  \right |<11\left |x-5  \right |$ if $4<x<6$
>
> (b) Find a $\delta$ such that $\left |x^2-25  \right |<10^{-3}$ if $0<\left |x-5  \right |<\delta$
>
> (c) Give a rigorous proof of the limit by showing that $\left |x^2-25  \right |<\epsilon$ if  $0<\left|x-5\right|<\delta$, where $\delta$ is the smaller of $\frac{\epsilon}{11}$ and $1$.

---

For (a):

$|x^2-25|<11|x-5|$

$|x+5||x-5|<11|x-5|$

$|x+5|<11$

$-16<x<6$

And ignoring the interval $[-16,4)$, $4<x<6$

---

For (b) and (c) I am unsure.

Comment: Your (a) is fine. So now use it. Suppose $|x-5|<\delta$. What can you conclude about $|x^2-25|$?

Comment: Just a small nitpick: You have to consider the case $x=5$ separately, because otherwise you are dividing both sides by zero when you go from $|x+5||x-5|<11|x-5|$ to $|x+5|<11$.

Comment: I think your (a) is a bit of an overkill: it enough to take the upper bound on $x: |x+5|<|6+5|=11$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** let's find a $\delta'$ so that $11|x-5| < 10^{-3}$ whenever $|x-5| < \delta'$.  If we select $\delta = \min\{\delta',1\}$, then we can guarantee that if $|x-5| < \delta$, then (since $x$ is necessarily between $4$ and $6$),
$$
|x^2 - 5| < 11|x - 5| < 10^{-3}
$$
For (c), all you should need to do is substitute $\epsilon$ for $10^{-3}$.

Answer (score 0):

If $0<|x-5|<\delta$ we have $$5-\delta<x<5+\delta\to 25-10\delta+\delta^2<x^2<25+10\delta+\delta^2$$therefore $$-11\delta<-10\delta<x^2-25<11\delta\\ |x^2-25|<11\delta$$ for any $0<\delta<1$. Now take $\delta\le \min\{1,{10^{-3}\over 11}\}={10^{-3}\over 11}$ (for example $\delta=0.0005$) and you are done.

For part c, just easily substitute $10^{-3}$ with $\epsilon $ and complete the proof.